# The IDE using for programming the Atlas robots

Tags: dynamics

[ATLAS Gets an Upgrade](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=27HkxMo6qK0) - the new video of the Atlas robot is out so I'm curious about the IDE with which they are coding this thing.

Comment: IDE, or just language and architecture in general, as I suspect there is not really an IDE per se. For an open government funded project, I find very few details available outside of the participants.

Comment: perhaps you actually meant API?

Comment: I know that they are using the ROS API, i'm asking about the IDE appearing on the video. Is this sublime text :D http://s3.postimg.org/oyggl7d77/image.png

Comment: From that screen shot I do not see anything that indicates ROS, the terminal window on the left has some lines with JRE in it, nothing ROS like (apt-get and GIT) and I'd personally be surprised if they used ROS (I sure wouldn't), but it is possible.  Sublime is an editor (like Vi or emacs), not an IDE. But yes, the window title appears to be Sublime.

Answer (score 2):

That definitely looks like Sublime to me...I'm pretty confident I can see Sublime's signature navigation window in the top right.

That being said...#VIM4Life